# Clubiing two lines into one using AWK

Tags: awk

I have a file with following format

```
 Time Number Val
  x    1     y
  x    1     y
  a    1     z
  b    1     m
  b    2     m
```

I want to club lines with same value, the final file should be something like this

```
 Time Number Val
  x    2     y
  a    1     z
  b    3     m
```

How to do this using awk?

Comment: What about the case `x 1 n`? That is a duplicate `Time` with a differnt `Val`. @KingsIndian and my answer treat this case different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk's associative array:

```
awk 'NR==1{print $0} NR!=1{a[$1]+=$2; b[$1]=$3;} \
 END{ for ( i in a)  print i, a[i], b[i]}' file
```

For your sample input, it prints:

```
Time Number Val
x 2 y
a 1 z
b 3 m
```

Comment: This will break for duplicates time with different values

Comment: Yes, it assumes `Val` is unique for corresponding `Time` (based on example input). If `Val` column will have different values for same `Time` values then there's no logical way add up second column. OP will have to clarify on what criteria he wants to calculate second column if they are dups in `Val` for same `Time`.

Comment: The logical way is just treat field 1 and 3 as a single key.. we shall see what OP wants for this case.

Comment: If F1 + F3 is considered as a single key then F1 will have duplicates in the final output when F3 is not unique wrt F1. I doubt that's what OP wants.

Comment: I think that is what the OP wants @Vishal? If you think that shouldn't you be using $3 as the key as the OP says `I want to club lines with same value`?

Answer (score 1):

Count all duplicate `Time` and `Val` combinations:

```
awk 'NR>1{a[$1,$3]+=$2;next}$1=$1;END{for(k in a){split(k,s,SUBSEP);print s[1],a[k],s[2]}}' OFS="\t" file
Time    Number  Val
a       1       z
b       3       m
x       2       y
```

Comment: +1. minimize the separator issue: `a[$1,$3]+=$2` then `split(k,s,SUBSEP)`. [Documented here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/User_002dmodified.html#User_002dmodified)